# How to use .babelrc plug-in options in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Options of a plug-in on `.babelrc` are like below:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Since I don't want to use `.babelrc`, but I intend to only use `webpack.config.js`, I need to add `"polyfill": false` and `"regenerator": true` options to my `webpack.config.js` file below,  How can I do that.

```
var webpack=require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    //configuration
    context: __dirname + '/src/ui/',
    entry: './ui.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            // "test" is commonly used to match the file extension
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            // "exclude" should be used to exclude exceptions
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 
                          'transform-class-properties', 'transform-runtime'],
            }
        }]
    },    
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/public/js/',
        filename: 'ui.bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

---

Looks like this modification on `webpack.config.js` works:

```
plugins: [
        'react-html-attrs', 
        'transform-decorators-legacy', 
        'transform-class-properties', 
        ['transform-runtime',{"polyfill": false, "regenerator": true}]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this modification on `webpack.config.js` works:

```
plugins: [
        'react-html-attrs', 
        'transform-decorators-legacy', 
        'transform-class-properties', 
        ['transform-runtime',{"polyfill": false, "regenerator": true}]
]
```